Looking for Minimal Example of Cucumber Running on a Lambda
I have a very specific use case here I want to at least understand better why it is not working..
So, the whole project uses Lerna, as well as Yarn workspaces. Typescript. Javascript. ESBuild, CDK. The structure is similar to:
- end-to-end
    - packages
        - cdk
        - scenario1
            - src
                index.ts
            - features
                lambda.features
            - support
                lambda.steps.ts
            package.json
            lerna.json
            build.js
            cucumber.js
            etc..
package.json
tsconfig.json

using Typescript, compiled to Javascript, CDK code written in TS that creates a simple Node lambda. Yarn to build. Lerna monorepo structure. Note that I may not have the structure and/or pathing 100% perfect in this example.. can ignore any small discrepancy
build.js
const { build } = require('esbuild');

const outputDir = 'dist';

const buildConfig = {
    bundle: true,
    entryPoints: ['src/index.ts', 'support/step-definitions/lambda.steps.ts'],
    external: ['path', 'fs'],
    minify: false,
    outdir: outputDir,
    sourcemap: true,
    target: 'node18'
};

build({
    ...buildConfig,
    platform: 'node'
}).catch(() => process.exit(1));

cucumber.json
{
    "sources": {
        "defaultDialect": "en",
        "paths": ["../features/*.feature"],
        "name": [],
        "order": "defined"
    },
    "support": {
        "importPaths": ["*.js"],
        "requireModules": [],
        "requirePaths": []
    },
    "formats": {
        "files": {
            "./reports/cucumber.html": "html"
        },
        "options": {},
        "publish": false,
        "stdout": "progress-bar"
    },
    "runtime": {
        "dryRun": false,
        "failFast": true,
        "filterStacktraces": false,
        "parallel": 3,
        "retry": 2,
        "retryTagFilter": "@flaky",
        "strict": true,
        "worldParameters": {}
    }
}

scenario1/package.json
{
    "name": "scenario1",
    "workspaces": {
        "nohoist": [
            "@cucumber/cucumber"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "build": "node build.js && cp -r features/ dist/features && cp cucumber.json dist",
    },
    "private": true,
    "files": [
        "dist/*"
    ],
    "main": "dist/index.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "@cucumber/cucumber": "^10.6.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@cucumber/cucumber": "^10.6.0"
    }
}

packages.json
{
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": ["packages/*"],
    "nohoist": ["**/scenario1/@cucumber/cucumber", "scenario1/@cucumber/**"]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "lerna run build",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "5.1.6",
    ...
  }
}

scenario1/src/index.ts
import cucumber = require('@cucumber/cucumber/lib/api/index');

export async function handler() {
    try {
        const testResult = await runCucumberTests();
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('An error occurred while executing Cucumber tests', error);
    }
}

async function runCucumberTests(): Promise<unknown> {

    const { runConfiguration } = await cucumber.loadConfiguration();
    const { success } = await cucumber.runCucumber(runConfiguration);
    return success;
}

handler(); // TODO: remove this line when running test or deploy

scenario1/support/lambda.steps.ts
import { Given, When, Then } from '@cucumber/cucumber';

Given('a given function', function () {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    return 'pending';
});

When('the when function', function () {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    return 'pending';
});


Then('there is a result', function () {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    return 'pending';
});

When running yarn install and yarn build and running the index.js in the /dist dir (and same in AWS lambda env) I get:

Error:
You're calling functions (e.g. "Given") on an instance of Cucumber that isn't running (status: PENDING).
This means you may have an invalid installation, potentially due to:
- Cucumber being installed globally
- A project structure where your support code is depending on a different instance of Cucumber
Either way, you'll need to address this in order for Cucumber to work.

I've tried all the suggestions for that error, but no luck.. Is there anything glaringly wrong with the build or how dependencies are brought in??
